# Cannot render raw HTML using ng-repeat and ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need have raw html which should be inserted to view `as is`.

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="el in tableRowsHTML track by $index" ng-bind-html="el">
                        {{el}}
 </tr>
 </table>

app.controller('Controller', function ($scope, promiseTemplateObj, $sce) {
$scope.tableRowsHTML = [];
$scope.generateTableRows = function(){ ....};

 $sce();
    $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.tableRowsHTML[1]);
    $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.tableRowsHTML[2]);
    $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.tableRowsHTML[3]);
```

How to fix it?

**UPDATE:**

I get it [partially working with ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444049/how-to-set-up-ngrepeat-to-generate-entries-stored-externally) but problem persists.

Comment: why not using the $compile service?

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr ng-repeat="el in tableRowsHTML track by $index" ng-bind-html="el | toTrusted"></tr>
```

Filter (just for example):

```
appRoot.filter('toTrusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
   return function (text) {
      return text ? $sce.trustAsHtml(text.replace(/\\n/g, '<br/>')) : '';
   };
}]);
```

Where appRoot - your application.

Update: example  http://jsfiddle.net/c5j92821/

Comment: Do you have an error or is it not working as you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look for [ng-sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) as well. This will help you in binding html from controller to the body. And have a look on this page for few of the [examples](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize)